# Youtube fullscreen doesn't work in WinForms webBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, video, youtube, webbrowser-control

I'm making a simple WinForms app and I'm having problems with trying to make a YouTube video fullscreen from the webBrowser control (when clicking on the embedded YouTube fullscreen button).

I've got a simple window with a webBrowser in it (no properties changed on the webBrowser other than "Dock", "ScrollBarsEnabled", and "Url"). The URL is, for example, https://www.youtube.com/v/qRv7G7WpOoU . After running in debug mode, if I click on the YouTube video's fullscreen button it does nothing.

Alternatively, if I use a link for a Vimeo video (e.g. https://player.vimeo.com/video/40767916 ), the fullscreen button from the Vimeo player works just fine.

(I have also tried using the Awesomium webControl with the same results)

Any insights into what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a javascript error, but if you post the code it will help. If you open the developer console when you load the page and also press the fullscreen button, are there any errors?

Comment: @KSib do you mean the "Output" window in Visual Studio? When I click the YouTube fullscreen button, this line gets written to the console: `'UniversalQueue.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UniversalQueue.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.mshtml\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.mshtml.dll'. Module was built without symbols.` Is that any help?

Comment: Oops, you said winforms and i read "webforms" over and over. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try that URL in a browser in Chrome at least you may notice that it won't display in full-screen either.

I tried this: 
`https://www.youtube.com/embed/qRv7G7WpOoU?controls=1&autohide=2` 
and it seemed to work.

Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters